# Expectation of $f(X)$, where $X$ is normally distributed and f is the PDF of the normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The question is

> What is the expectation of $f(X)$? where $X \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ and $f$ is the PDF of $\mathcal N(0, 1)$

I think in this case we have

$$
E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \times f(x) dx
$$
$$
E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} (e^{-x^2/2})^2 dx
$$

$$
E(X) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{{\pi}}}
$$

Am I right there? I don't have solutions for this question so validation of my approach (either way) would be appreciated. I could not find a similar question when searching (probably because I found wording the question hard). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks right: With $\sigma^2=1/2$ we have
\begin{align}
E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-x^2}\, dx=
 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}\, dx}_{1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Looks right to me. Another way of doing it is:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[f(a + X)\right] &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d a}\mathbb E\left[\Phi\left(a + X\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d a}\mathbb E\left[\mathbb P\left[Y \le a+X \Big | X\right]\right]\\
&= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d a}\mathbb P\left[Y - X \le a\right]\\
&= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d a} \Phi\left(\frac{a - 0}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt 2}f\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}\right)
\end{align}

For $a = 0$ you have your equality.