# Is anything known about plugging a Normal random variable into the pdf for a different normal?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, normal-distribution

Suppose we have a Normal random variable $X$ with the cdf

$$\displaystyle P(   X \le x) = \int_{a}^x \frac{\exp \left(  -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{ t-\mu_1 }{\sigma_1 }\right)^2  \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}dt$$

If we plug this into its own pdf we get a uniformally distributed random variable (**Edit:** Actually I should write cdf and not pdf)

$$\displaystyle   \int_{-\infty}^X \frac{\exp \left(  -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{ t-\mu_1 }{\sigma_1 }\right)^2  \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}dt \qquad \text{ is uniform on }[0,1]. $$

In fact this holds for any random variable $X$ with sufficiently nice cdf $F$. Plug it into its own cdf and you get a uniformly distributed variable on the range of the cdf.

---

**Added Later:**

Since $F(X)$ takes values in $[0,1]$ we only need to consider $x \in [0,1]$ when deriving the cdf of $F(X)$:

$P(F(X) \le x) = P(X \le F^{-1}(X)) = P(X \le y) = F(y) = F (F^{-1} (x)) = x$.

Hence the pdf of $F(X)$ is zero before $x=0$, equal to $1$ after increases linearly to $1$ at $x=1$, and $F(x) =x$ on $[0,1]$. That's a uniform random variable.

---

But what if we plug $X$ into the pdf of a different normal with different mean and variance?

$$\text{how is }  \int_{-\infty}^X \frac{\exp \left(  -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{ t-\mu_2 }{\sigma_2 }\right)^2  \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} dt \text{ distributed }?  $$

I'd expect in general thee things cannot be written out explicitly. But since the normal curve is so well-studied I would not be surprised if the above at least has a name. Does anyone know?

Comment: Plugging a variable into its cdf produces a uniform variable not its pdf.

Comment: Like @athalhaids said, the cdf version is correct. Have you gone through the proof of that assertion? Do you understand why that's true? And how would you alter the proof for a different normal variable?

Comment: Plugging a normal r.v. into the normal *PDF* is handled very elegantly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4723113/949989). At least as far as the expectation is concerned. To talk about a pdf of a *different* normal variable only makes sense when mean or variance are different. Should not complicate things that much.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The proof of what?

Comment: @KurtG. With the same cdf the proof has nothing to do with how things are normal. With a different cdf, you get a nasty expression involving the integral of one Gaussian function of the inverse of another.

Comment: @Daron How do you prove that plugging a random variable into its cdf gives a uniform distribution? Even a sketch of a proof with the pathologies waved away for the moment is fine for now, but how would you do it?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'll add it to the question

Comment: @Daron . Fully agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ and $X_2\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)\,.$ We know that the **CDFs** are
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\{X_i\le x\}=\mathbb P\Big\{\underbrace{\frac{X_i-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}}_{\sim N(0,1)}\le \frac{x-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}\Big\}=\Phi\Big(\frac{x-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}\Big)\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal **CDF**:
$$
\Phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^ze^{-y^2/2}\,dy\,.\tag{2}
$$
Q. What is the distribution of $X_2$ plugged into the **CDF** of $X_1\,?$

A. It has the **CDF**
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\Bigg\{\Phi\Big(\frac{X_2-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\Big)\le x\Bigg\}&=\mathbb P\Big\{X_2\le \sigma_1\Phi^{-1}(x)+\sigma_1\mu_1\Big\}\\
&=\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\sigma_1\Phi^{-1}(x)+\sigma_1\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sigma_2} \Bigg)\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
Sanity check: when $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ and $\mu_1=\mu_2$ the RHS collapses to $x$ as it should be the case for a uniform distribution.

In the general case you can now obtain the **PDF** by taking the derivative of (3) w.r.t. $x\,.$ It does not matter how nasty that expression will be or what name it has but it is doable.

Comment: I understand all this. But I wonder can the object (3) be simplified or studied in the case that $\Phi$ is the normal CDF?

Comment: @Daron $\Phi$ *is* the normal CDF and we are already studying (3) here. I don't hink we need someone else to take the derivative for us.

Comment: Yeah but does it have a name or a closed form?

Comment: It has a closed form (take derivative). Name ? I don't know. I think you should look at copulas and how similar ideas are used to correlate two random variables by plugging them into a two-dimensional normal CDF.